# Python 3: Best practice way to validate/parse **kwargs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, keyword-argument

I am trying to learn more about Python - I am using 3.6.3 currently.

What is the best practice for argument validation/parsing when using kwargs?

Or, what is the best practice for argument validation/parsing without kwargs?

```
class foo:
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    if 'a' in kwargs:
      self.a = kwargs['a']
    else:
      self.a = 0

class bar(foo):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__()
    if 'x' in kwargs:
      self.x = kwargs['x']
    else:
      self.x = 23

# b and y are undefined, but my classes use kwargs - what is the best practice for validating / parsing dynamic arguments?
test = bar(b=1,y=24)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can pass a default value to get() for keys that are not in the `kwargs` dictionary:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.a = kwargs.get("a", 0)
    self.x = kwargs.get("x", 23)
    # etc.
```

Alternatively if you want any value in `kwargs` to be set as an instance variable of your class, you could do:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        self.__setattr__(k, v)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Foo:
   def __init__(self,a=0):
       self.a = a

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self,b=21,**kwargs):
        self.b = b  # accept whatever you want for this child
        Foo.__init__(self,**kwargs) # pass remaining kwargs down the line
```

does exactly what your Foo class does and is much more clear

most problems with using kwargs come from the fact that its not at all self documenting ... I have no idea what arguments can and should be supplied for neither `Foo` or `Bar` where as explicitly declared arguments with default values make it very clear what options are available to pass into the functions

Comment: I understand that, and that is exactly my question - is there a best practice way for attempting to validate arguments when using kwargs, or the best practice is just to create more well defined and less dynamic classes or child classes?

Comment: The more common case where `**kwargs` is used, to my knowledge, is when either (a) the class you are inheriting is one you don't own or control, or (b) when you are not in fact inheriting the class. [`pandas.read_hdf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_hdf.html) offers a nice example: it is using `pytables`, which incorporates HDF5, and (presumably) with so many potential changes out of its control, that `read_hdf` method has its own parameters, followed by `**kwargs`, which is just passed up the stream to be used by `pytables`.

Comment: this is definately true ... but is not counter to my point about the problems with kwargs either